# Detecting foreign words

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

I am writing a script to detect words from a language B in a language A. The two languages are very similar and may have instances of the same words.

The code is here if you are interested in what I have so far:
https://github.com/arashsa/language-detection.git

I will explain my method here:
I create a list of bigrams in language B, a list of bigrams in language A (small corpus in language B, large corpus in language A). Then I remove all bigrams that are common. Then I go through the text in language A, and using the bigrams I detect these in language A and store them in a file. However, this methods finds many words that are common for both languages, and it also finds strange bigrams like the name of two countries adjacent to each other, and other anomalies.

Do any of you have suggestions, reading material, NLP methods that I might use?

Comment: What kind of languages are you trying to detect?

Comment: There are many methods to detect languages, if script is based on UNICODE, it is very easy to detect the language.

Comment: Well, the languages are nynorsk and bokmaal (which are two variants of Norwegian, but they can be classified as two distinct languages I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your method is returning words present in both languages, and you only want to return words that exist in one language, you might want to create a list of *one-grams* in language A and one-grams in language B, and then remove the words in both. Then, if you like, you can proceed with the bigram analysis.

That said, there are some good tools in Python for language identification. I've found `lang-id` to be one of the best. It comes pre-trained with language classifiers for over 90 languages, and is fairly easy to train for additional languages if you like. Here are the [docs](https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py). There is also [guess-language](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess-language), but it doesn't perform as well in my estimation. Depending on how localized the bits of foreign language are, you could try chunking your texts at an appropriate level of granularity and running those chunks through (e.g.) langid's classifier.

Comment: Wow, thanks, it actually has a model for nynorsk, the language I want to detect. Man, I spent a few days writing my script...

Comment: I know the feeling! I guess it's always good to know thy data, so hopefully not all of the time you spent with the script feels like time wasted. Enjoy langid!

Comment: Well, it was not for nothing, as lang-id seems to be terrible at the distinction between nynorsk and bokmaal (the two norwegian languages). I tried giving it from two words to 30 words at a time, and the times it thought it found nynorsk it was bokmaal, noe one instance of nynorsk actually, so it might find nynorsk, but so far it has only mistakenly tagged bokmaal as nynorsk.

Comment: Hmm, you might try feeding the classifier additional training data, if it's available...