# How detect foreign words in Corpus?

Tags: r, text-mining

Suppose I am parsing an english corpus with the `tm` package, and I do the usual cleaning steps.

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
corpus <- Corpus(crude)

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(removeWords)) stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)

# text matrices
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
dtm<- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

How do I identify the words written in a different language than the one of the corpus? A similar problem is faced with [Python here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191457/detecting-foreign-words), but my research did not produces interesting results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but I feel like it might help. I recently had to do something similar where I had to remove words from a corpus with Chinese characters. I ended up using a custom transformation with a regex to remove anything with a non a-z 0-9 character in it.

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(function(s){
  gsub(pattern = '[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+',
       x = s,
       replacement = " ",
       ignore.case = TRUE,
       perl = TRUE)
}))
```

For example, if there is a Chinese word in there, it gets removed.

```
gsub(pattern = '[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+',
     x = 'English 象形字 Chinese',
     replacement = "",
     ignore.case = TRUE,
     perl = TRUE)
```

Output: "English  Chinese"

It's trickier if you are trying to remove words from a language like Spanish because some letters have an accent while others don't. For example, this doesn't work completely, but maybe it's a start.

```
gsub(pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
     x = 'El jalapeño es caliente',
     replacement = "",
     ignore.case = TRUE,
     perl = TRUE)
```

Output: "El  es caliente"

Hope this helps!